# How to check for user perms (DISCORDIA)

Tags: discord, luvit

The title speaks for itself, please help, pretty please.

Comment: Do you want to use any discord library? Or do you just want to know how to do it via raw Discord API?

Comment: @DavidMoškoř oh im sorry, i want to use discordia

Comment: `message` has `member` property. See here: https://github.com/SinisterRectus/Discordia/wiki/Message

Comment: @DavidMoškoř yes i know that, i am using it to allow commands in dms. now that you edited it i can say that i definitely know it

Comment: Ok. If you read the documentation you can see, that the `member` class has an `hasPermission` function. https://github.com/SinisterRectus/Discordia/wiki/Member

Comment: @DavidMoškoř thanks! although, how does it work? like this maybe member:hasPermission(BAN_USERS)  ?

Comment: I'll post an answer.

Comment: @DavidMoškoř ok

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `member` class contains `hasPermission` function. So the code to check if message author has permission would look like this:

```
if message.member:hasPermission(banMembers) then
    -- do action
end
```

Useful links:

- Lua documentation: https://github.com/SinisterRectus/Discordia/wiki/
- All permision's enums: https://github.com/SinisterRectus/Discordia/wiki/Enumerations#permission

Comment: it gives off an error 
`Uncaught Error: D:/Bot/deps/coro-channel.lua:62: D:/Bot/deps/discordia/libs/utils/Emitter.lua:105: Invalid permission: nil`

Comment: I see. The documentation say that the first parameter is optional so i passed `nil`. But it seems like documentation is outdated. Simply remove the first parameter. I'll update my answer.